# Postman cannot connecto NodeJS server even if its running?

Tags: node.js

I wrote this code in my node app

```
const express = require("express");

const cors = require("cors");
const pool = require("./db");
const app = express();
//middleware
app.use(cors);
//access req.body

app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.json("response from server");
    // const allCompanies = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM COMPANIES");

    // res.json(allCompanies.rows);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
});

const port = 1337;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is starting on port ${port}`);
});
```

In my terminal it says its running on 1337 however when i try to connect to postman it leaves me hanging? never had this problem before.

Comment: Your code works here. Can you provide some more information about the problem?

Comment: I'm in postman GET request to "http://localhost:1337"
And its stuck in Sending Request

Comment: Says Error: socket hang up

Comment: check if your DB is running on the same port as your server too.

Comment: and check the url, it might sound too simple but it happened to me a lot too.

Comment: im conecting to postgresql and it postgres uses 5432 port

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const express = require("express");

const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
```

The problem was that you were not calling the cors function on your app.use middleware.

If you change the code to

```
    app.use(cors());
```

It should work.

[Express Documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html)